# What is the string format "%g%%" mean in python 3?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, python-2.7, format

According to python 3 document, the string formating "%%" means "a perncet sign".

Following code is an example:

```
"%g%%" % 10.34 == "10.34%"
```

I am not sure what does this "%g" mean here, I suspect it should have the same meaning 
as "%g" in string formating, which is "Shorter one among %f or %e". and "%f" or "%e" means 
"floating point real number" or "Exponential notaion, lowercase'e'".
Example of them are:

```
"%f" % 10.34 == '10.34000'
```

or

```
"%e" % 1000 == '1.000000e+03'
```

Based on this understanding, I tried follwoing code. I treid to formatting x first,
and then directly use formating string "%%", but it does not work.

```
x = '%g' % 10.34
print(isinstance(x, float)) #this returns false
"%%" % x == "10.34%" # this returns error
```

I then tried this:

```
x = float(10.34)
print(isinstance(x, float)) #this returns true
"%%" % x == "10.34%" # this returns error as well
```

I even tried this:

```
x = "10.34000"
"%%" % x == "10.34%" # this returns error as well
```

Anyone know what is going on here with "%%". What its mean, do we have to use "%g%%" together with "%%" in any circumstance?

This is solved, the question comes from the misleading of the book. I made comments here:
[image]

Comment: If `%` is a meta character, how would you include an actual `%` in the *output* of the formatting result? The answer is `%%`. The `%%` sequence doesn't format any other values, it formats the `%` in the output.

Comment: Yes. you are right. I now understand. "%%" is not a format but a way to output sign "%". Therefore we must include a format when using "%%", this format can be "%d", "%f" or "%s" etc..

Comment: **If** you use the string as a template for printf-style formatting with the `%` operator, then `%` characters in the template string have special meaning. You can use `%%` without other metacharacters: `"This works: %%" % ()`, but that's a bit pointless, right?

Comment: Yes. you are right.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since `%` introduces a format, there must be some way to specify a literal `%`; that way is `%%`.

```
>>> print("%s%%" % "foo")
foo%
```

It's analogous to how `\\` specifies a literal backslash in a string.